# Swapping database rows

Tags: sql

I have 4 columns in a table. Right now it is in this format:

```
Action   Value_XML            Control_ID        Data_Value
-----------------------------------------------------------
SEARCH  <ACTION v="SEARCH"/>     SEARCH          SEARCH
SEARCH  <BROKERREF v="BZ815"/>   BROKERREF       BZ815
SEARCH  <SYSTEM v="  0"/>        SYSTEM            0
Chg     <ACTION v="Chg"/>         Chg             Chg
Chg     <BROKERREF v="BZ815"/>   BROKERREF       BZ815
Chg     <SYSTEM v="  0"/>        SYSTEM            0
```

I need to get the below format:

```
Action   Value_XML            Control_ID        Data_Value
-----------------------------------------------------------         
SEARCH  <SYSTEM v="  0"/>        SYSTEM            0
SEARCH  <BROKERREF v="BZ815"/>   BROKERREF       BZ815  
SEARCH  <ACTION v="SEARCH"/>     SEARCH          SEARCH
Chg     <SYSTEM v="  0"/>        SYSTEM            0
Chg     <BROKERREF v="BZ815"/>   BROKERREF       BZ815
Chg     <ACTION v="Chg"/>         Chg             Chg
```

Note: I need to update the rows as follows:

Row 1 and row 3 should be swapped (when Control_id and DataValue are the same it should be the last row)
Row 4 and row 6 should be swapped (when Control_id and DataValue are the same it should be the last row)

Note: Here the row count is dynamic, it is not necessary we have only 3 rows.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to change the order when you do a SELECT? Use ORDER BY, probably combined with CASE

Comment: sql tables are not sorted, in any relational database I know of. 
the order of the rows in a table is absolutely meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

You don't include a query or table details, or even what database you are using, so it's hard to speak with certainty.

In general, though, sql databases return records in arbitrary order. If you want your results in some specific order, you must include an appropriate ORDER BY clause, which in this case would seem to be on the last column.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, the two data sets are identical, only the order of rows differs. With that said, I *think* the following would provide what your are looking for:

```
SELECT Action, Value_XML, Control_ID, Data_Value
 from MyTable
 order by
   Action
  ,case
     when Control_ID = DataValue then 1  --  This assumes the datatypes can be compared
     else 0
   end
  ,Value_XML
```

(You can do unlikely things with `case` statements in the `order by` clause...)